# Need to calculate age using TIMESTAMPDIFF() function based on year of birth but some row return null value

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Please someone help me to check my sql statement. I want to calculate people age based on year but there are some row not return the actual value. but null. Pardon my english. Hope you guys understand my question. This is my sql statement :

```
select no_id,
    case when substring(no_id,1,2) <Substring(YEAR(NOW()),-2) 
    then Concat('20',substring(no_id,1,2),'-'  ,substring(no_id,3,2),'-', substring(no_id,5,2))
    else
     Concat('19',substring(no_id,1,2),'-'  ,substring(no_id,3,2),'-', substring(no_id,5,2))
    end as dob, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, no_id, CURDATE()) AS age
from driver_details;
```

my actual table input like this:

| no_id | category_license | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 980401001121 | D | 1 |
| 970101110101 | D | 1 |

my output after I run the sql statement in phpmyadmin:

| no_id | dob | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 980401001121 | 1998-04-01 | 24 |
| 970101110101 | 1997-01-01 | NULL |

This is expecetd value that I want to return in my table in database.

| no_id | dob | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 980401001121 | 1998-04-01 | 24 |
| 970101110101 | 1997-01-01 | 25 |

Comment: Can't be answered without knowing your input data. Please always show both sample input and the expected result when asking SQL questions, not one of that only.

Comment: What does `show warnings;` immediately after running the select show?

Comment: I assume those are yy mm dd hh mm ss values in no_id?  Try using the same expression in your timestampdiff call as you have for dob, since just treating the string as a date isn't working in all cases

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/bPy_yL7M Provide the fiddle with your structure/data which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Show `hex(no_id)` for the rows getting nulls

Comment: @JonasMetzler My sample data show above. I already edit the question.

Comment: @ysth the first 6 numbers no_id is actually based on date of birth of that person. for example 980401 is same with 1998-04-01

Comment: Can still not be replicated, see here the result of the query is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/vIhMtI5h Please provide a fiddle which shows the problem.

Comment: You'll get `NULL` when any of your columns or partial expressions are `NULL`. Show every individual bit in the `SELECT` clause until you identify the culprit.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/2R4Ro5SC @JonasMetzler it is still show the same output here.

Comment: What should "840312135169" be? I thought this string should represent date and time. But a minute only has 60 seconds, so this is invalid. Must be something like "840312135159" or "840312135149" instead?

Comment: the first 6 numbers is actually the date of birth. for example "840312135169" is 1984-03-12. the rest after six number which is 135169 is just random numbers. not represent time or anything. @JonasMetzler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you want to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on the entire `no_id`.
This is incorrect because this would only work correctly if the string represents a valid datetime.

This is not the case for your samples like `840312135169` because the "69" at the end would be read as seconds, but a minute has 60 seconds only.

So you need to either provide a valid datetime in this column or you only run `TIMESTAMPDIFF` on the first part of your column which is a valid date and ignore the rest:

```
select no_id,
case when substring(no_id,1,2) <Substring(YEAR(NOW()),-2) 
  then Concat('20',substring(no_id,1,2),'-'  ,
    substring(no_id,3,2),'-', substring(no_id,5,2))
  else Concat('19',substring(no_id,1,2),'-'  ,
    substring(no_id,3,2),'-', substring(no_id,5,2)) 
end as dob,  
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, substring(no_id,1,6), CURDATE()) AS age -- changed here
from driver_license;
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n5gLBdRp)

Comment: Wow good. I understand. Thank you very much because your answer can help me solve this problem.